# Drawer hides page content when open

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have a drawer component. Now, when I open it, it hides the page contents. I just to to make it push the content to the right so it's still visible to the user. Can someone help me achieve this? It would be appreciated

```
import React from "react";

interface DrawerProps {
  isOpen: boolean;

  onClose: () => void;
}

const Drawer: React.FC<DrawerProps> = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <div
      id="drawer-navigation"
      className={`fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform ${
        isOpen ? "translate-x-0" : "-translate-x-full"
      } bg-white w-64 dark:bg-gray-800`}
      tabIndex={-1}
      aria-labelledby="drawer-navigation-label"
    >
      <h5
        id="drawer-navigation-label"
        className="text-base font-semibold text-gray-500 uppercase dark:text-gray-400"
      >
        Menu
      </h5>

      <button
        type="button"
        data-drawer-hide="drawer-navigation"
        aria-controls="drawer-navigation"
        className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 absolute top-2.5 end-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
        onClick={onClose}
      >
        <svg
          className="w-3 h-3"
          aria-hidden="true"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 14 14"
        >
          <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"
          />
        </svg>

        <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
      </button>

      <div className="py-4 overflow-y-auto">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#"
                className="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 group"
              >
                <svg
                  className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 22 21"
                >
                  <path d="M16.975 11H10V4.025a1 1 0 0 0-1.066-.998 8.5 8.5 0 1 0 9.039 9.039.999.999 0 0 0-1-1.066h.002Z" />

                  <path d="M12.5 0c-.157 0-.311.01-.565.027A1 1 0 0 0 11 1.02V10h8.975a1 1 0 0 0 1-.935c.013-.188.028-.374.028-.565A8.51 8.51 0 0 0 12.5 0Z" />
                </svg>

                <span className="ms-3">Dashboard</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Drawer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using `position: fixed`. This removes the drawer from the DOM layout, making it more difficult to have it "push" content. Instead, you could consider using a CSS grid layout parent that changes the grid column track width of the drawer, thus pushing the content when it is open:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Drawer = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <div
      id="drawer-navigation"
      className={`relative p-4 h-screen overflow-y-auto bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 min-w-0 justify-self-end w-64`}
      tabIndex={-1}
      aria-labelledby="drawer-navigation-label"
    >
      <h5
        id="drawer-navigation-label"
        className="text-base font-semibold text-gray-500 uppercase dark:text-gray-400"
      >
        Menu
      </h5>

      <button
        type="button"
        data-drawer-hide="drawer-navigation"
        aria-controls="drawer-navigation"
        className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 absolute top-2.5 end-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
        onClick={onClose}
      >
        <svg
          className="w-3 h-3"
          aria-hidden="true"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 14 14"
        >
          <path
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"
          />
        </svg>

        <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
      </button>

      <div className="py-4 overflow-y-auto">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a
                href="#"
                className="flex items-center p-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg dark:text-white hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 group"
              >
                <svg
                  className="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 transition duration-75 dark:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-900 dark:group-hover:text-white"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 22 21"
                >
                  <path d="M16.975 11H10V4.025a1 1 0 0 0-1.066-.998 8.5 8.5 0 1 0 9.039 9.039.999.999 0 0 0-1-1.066h.002Z" />

                  <path d="M12.5 0c-.157 0-.311.01-.565.027A1 1 0 0 0 11 1.02V10h8.975a1 1 0 0 0 1-.935c.013-.188.028-.374.028-.565A8.51 8.51 0 0 0 12.5 0Z" />
                </svg>

                <span className="ms-3">Dashboard</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div class={`grid transition-[grid-template-columns] ${isOpen ? 'grid-cols-[theme(width.64)_1fr]' : 'grid-cols-[0%_1fr]'}`}>
      <Drawer isOpen={isOpen} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} />
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
          Open
        </button>
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```